# How do I pass an object as a parameter to a method without affecting the object?

Tags: java

I have an object - `Mat` - of class `Matrix` which has an `arrayList` of Integers. Now I need to pass `Mat` to a method called `getAdjugateMatrix` which will use the values of `Mat`'s `ArrayList` and return me another `Matrix` object, but I don't want `adjugateMatrix` to change `Mat` at all. How can I achieve that? Will it work if I set `Mat` to final, do `Matrix temp = mat`, and then pass temp to `getAdjugateMatrix`? TIA

Comment: Make a function that creates a deep copy of your `Matrix` class, and pass it instead.

Comment: You pass a copy/clone (or do so in the receiver), or don't modify it.

Comment: If you're in control of the `getAdjugateMatrix` method, you could just add 'I will not modify my inputs' as part of the contract.  Or make `Matrix` immutable as a type.

Comment: Can you add the relevant pieces of your code in the question?

Comment: Setting a variable to `final` means that it's value may not change once set. This behaviour is obvious for primitives, but for objects you should note that the value that is unchangeable by virtue of being `final` is in fact a reference/pointer to the object; the object itself may still be manipulated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use clone

Example

```
Student18 s1=new Student18(101,"amit");  
  
Student18 s2=(Student18)s1.clone();
```

Comment: it is a link https://www.javatpoint.com/object-cloning

Comment: the clone method only works for shallow objects; it is broken for deep objects.

Answer (score 3):

> How do i pass an object as a parametre to a method without affecting the object?

You cannot, by default. When you pass an object as an argument, the receiving method can use that object in any manner as it sees fit.

The Comments outlined the possible solutions:

- Make a [deep copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Deep_copy). Pass a new object with a Xerox copy, a clone, of all the data. Now the receiving method can make all the changes it wants without disturbing the original. See the Question, [*How do I copy an object?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/869033/642706).
- Redesign the class of your passed object to be [immutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). For examples of immutable objects, see the *java.time* classes, and the new `List.of`, `Set.of`, and `Map.of` methods.
- Document the argument as being under the “honor system” with the receiving method’s programmer promising to not modify the passed argument. Obviously this is unreliable as it depends on programmers’ awareness and memory. So I would not recommend this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the method create a clone of Mat ,do the change you want althen return clone.If you only set Matrix temp = mat,temp will be a reference for accessing mat so when you change temp attributes'values it will affect mat as well that's why you should clone it